# How can I make mule configuration to poll

Tags: mule, polling

I am new with mule.

I am using mule 3.2

this is my xml file.

```
 <model name="polltest">
    <service name="poll">
        <inbound>
            <tcp:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="35466" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        </inbound>
        <outbound>
            <pass-through-router>
                <tcp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="45511" connector-ref="tcplengthProtocol" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
            </pass-through-router>
        </outbound>
    </service>
</model>
```

i have to poll "Check Message" string message every 5 minutes to port 45511 how coult i do this ?

help whith some example codes T ^ T

thanks.

Comment: If you are new to mule you should really consider using flows rather than services :) That said could you please clarify your usecase? Do you want to start your processing when the "Check Message" has been published on port 45511? Or do you waht to establish a connection to port 35466 every 5 mins and then check what has been published on the other socket?

Comment: hm .. i want to establish port 45511 using keepalive property true. Then i want send "Check Message" string every 5 mins.